# Marklogic querying on HDFS

Tags: marklogic

Is it possible to search and query the data on hdfs from Marklogic server without importing the data into Marklogic server database?? I have been able to import the data into Marklogic server database.But not able to find any details on how to query data without importing.If there are ways please help on how to do so????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "query". To query data in any meaningful way, the data needs to be in a database. But HDFS is not a database.

If you want to keep forests on HDFS, you can do that: see the [MarkLogic HDFS docs](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/disk-storage#id_27091).

If you want to treat HDFS like a local filesystem, built-in functions like `xdmp:filesystem-directory` and `xdmp:filesystem-get` seem to accept `hdfs://` URLs. Note that you'll need to configure MarkLogic as an HDFS client, as described in the [MarkLogic HDFS docs](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/performance/disk-storage#id_27091). Otherwise any attempt to access HDFS this way will throw `SVC-HDFSNOT`.

Alternatively if you can set up or build an HTTP REST-ish interface on HDFS, you could use `xdmp:http-get` and related functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are connectors that  can be used from Marklogic, but you need to  build your sequence file  with Key, Value pair